# How to convert Option[RDD] into RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hashmap, rdd

I am storing RDD into mutable Hashmap using some key as below.

```
var datasets = new HashMap[String, RDD[T]]()
val feedRdd: RDD[T] = ...
datasets.put("someKey", feedRdd)
```

Now I am trying to fetch the same rdd from Hashmap and it is returning Option[RDD[T]] as below

```
val feedRddNew = datasets.get("someKey")
```

And it is giving error something like this.

> Expression of type Option[RDD[T]] doesn't confirm to expected type
>   RDD[T]

Basically I want to store rdd into Hashmap so that I can fetch it from Hashmap as I needed. Any thoughts on this? Please let me know if something is wrong or any alternate way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val feedRddNew = datasets.get("someKey")
```

This getter returns an Option[T] where T is the type stored in the map.

So, either None, or Some(T)

so you can do

```
val theActualValue = feedRddNew.get
```

or, you can just use

```
datasets("someKey")
```

which doesnt return an option (it just throws if the key is not found)

Comment: Thank you so much. Both are working as expected.